# How to attach a file using SubmitForm() in Codeception

Tags: php, codeception

I'm testing a form through the `SubmitForm()` function because the form uses javascript to cycle through each individual item.

**example:**

```
$I->submitForm('#form', array(
    'feet' => '1',
    'inches' => '2',

), 'submit');
```

This works fine but I'm having trouble with a file upload input.

```
$I->submitForm('#form', array(
    'feet' => '1',
    'inches' => '2',
    'file' => ???

 ), 'submit');
```

I tried sending an array to mimic the `$_FILES` array but that obviously isn't the right way to do it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realise this is old and already marked as answer but it doesn't answer the specific question, which is still a problem for @alexleonard, who posted the accepted answer.

You can user `attachFile` in conjunction with `submitForm`. You just have to call is first. For example:

```
$I->attachFile('#form input[type=file]', <pathtofile> );
$I->submitForm('#form', array(
    'feet' => '1',
    'inches' => '2',
), 'submit');
```

Comment: I confirm that it works and that it responds much better to the problem

Answer (score 9):

I've encountered this issue as well and the only way I can see around it is to manually fill the fields and the click the submit button.

For example

```
$I->fillField(['name' => 'name'], 'Test');
$I->attachFile('input[name=photo]', 'test.jpg');
$I->click('#formId button[type=submit]');
$I->seeCurrentRouteIs('route.index');
$I->see('Model has been updated.');
```

You can store any test files in the Codeception tests/_data folder.

This does work, but sadly doesn't help me in my current situation as I have a form which dynamically populates various select elements so I need to `submitForm` as I can't manually `selectOption` as the options are populated depending on other form completions.